# Sqlite: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed on remove

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to automatically delete all the entries in a table with foreign key constraint, when I delete the key itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; that's what [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) does.